Is it theoretically possible to discover a prime-checking algorithm with the time complexity of $O(\ln n)$ or $O(1)$?
I was just playing around and was trying to make a algorithm for primality testing with the target time complexity of $O(\ln n)$. I'm new to the concept of time complexity and was wondering is it theoretically possible to discover a prime-checking algorithm with the time complexity of $O(\ln n)$ or even $O(1)$?

You will never get a prime checking algorithm that doesn't involve looking at every digit of the prime number in the chosen base.
That would a lower bound of be $O(n)$ where $n$ is the number of digits (which the log of the prime number to be checked).
